# Correctly using

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I would like to congratulate my friend's wife. But I am not sure how to say on German

> Heute ist die Frauen Tag. Grüßen sie bitte Frau Mager von mir und senden meine Glückwünsche...

Will be it correct?

Comment: Hello Nani, welcome to this forum. Unfortunately, it is not a forum for simply asking for translations such as for things like "*Heute ist Weltfrauentag. Grüßen Sie Ihre Frau von mir und richten Sie ihr meine Glückwünsche aus*" or whatever. You should post here specific questions for German language, its grammar, its registers of speech, etc. Questions should be of possible use also for others who are interested in German language. And you should show your own attempts to solve the problem (which you, in this case, did to a certain degree by providing your sample sentence).

Comment: @Christian: "Grüßen Sie **bitte** Ihre Frau von mir ... ". ;-)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  Herrje, wie konnte ich das vergessen! Nehmen Sie bitte meine Entschuldigung an und grüßen Sie Ihre Frau von mir recht herzlich!

Comment: Frauentag wird im Deutschen zusammengeschrieben. Weil es "der Tag" ist, ist es auch "der Frauentag".

Comment: ,@userunknown  ... man könnte aber, in etwas altertümlicher Ausdrucksweise auch "*der Frauen Tag*" sagen und das *der* als Artikel zu *Frauen* im Genitiv Plural verstehen (umgestellt dann *"Tag der Frauen"*). - Siehe auch das berühmte Verslein:  "***Heute ist der Frauen Tag. Es grüße sie, wer Frauen mag.***"

Answer (score 1):

*heute ist die Frauen Tag.*

- German sentences start with a capital letter, hence ***H***eute.
- German does not allow rows of nouns as English does. Instead, it allows even more wicked compound words created on the spot. The gender of those compounds depend on the last component, and as it's *der Tag*, it must be **der Frauentag**. You may use it with or without the definite article. Most other special days as *Ostersonntag* or *Silvester* are used without article.

*Grüßen sie bitte Frau Mager von mir und senden meine Glückwünsche...*

- The personal pronoun has to be the formal *Sie*, not the plural *sie*. The difference is just the capitalization. Take care.
- In the last part, you left out a second, required *Sie* after *senden*. You can often leave out repeated words from list items, but either starting from the beginning or starting from the end of the list item. Not from right within.
- The verb *senden* is quite odd. Better verbs for that action are *überbringen* or *ausrichten*.